# How many types of Nymphs were there?

Tags: greek, nymphs

After reading and answering [this question](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/1544/was-charybdis-always-a-monster), it caused me to believe that in Greek mythology, there were a lot of nymphs. They were nature spirits, and so, there are a lot of *types* of nymphs.

> Cloud - Nephelai (Cloud-Nymphs)
>
> Grass - Leimonides (Pasture Nymphs)<sub>(Close enough to grass)</sub>
>
> Flower - Anthousai (Flower Nymphs)

All from [here](http://www.theoi.com/Nymphe/Okeanides.html).

So what other nymphs were there?

Comment: As far as an answer, the [theoi page on Nymphai](http://www.theoi.com/Nymphe/Nymphai.html#List) has quite a nice list, including references if you scroll down a bit.  Just too much to cover for me to want to attempt an actual answer, though.

Comment: Maybe I'll place a bounty....

Comment: If you like.  Personally, I still won't attempt it, though.  Look at the Theoi list.  It's supported by 19 quotes from 10 authors written over the course of over 1000 years (and it's not quite complete by it's own admission).  I'm almost inclined to say this is may just be too broad to be answered here.

Comment: Oh look, someone's referenced one of my questions.

Answer (score 4):

Nymphs are associated with nature, and nature is expansive. This [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nymph) has a list near the bottom of Nymphs, their names, and their classification by dwelling. Classification tends to overlap and it's not always clear.

Obviously with any Mythology there are uncertainties, Nymphs fortunately are one of the easier of the uncertainties. Because they are associated with nature there are the broad categories that they can fit in like Celestial, Land, Wood, etc. which makes listing them a bit easier.